# Purpose of using CATEGORY_HOME in android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

What is the alternative to removing the following from AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity           

    android:name="com.apper.main.UserActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"        
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

I also found that after removing the above line, there was no impact to my android
application. What's the main use of this category and what's the alternative to it.

If the intent of this category is to launch the home screen then it can be done by the following:

```
Intent homeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

This above code will launch the home screen but why the line in the android manifest ?
What's the purpose as removing the line from here does nothing change the application ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the main use of this category

It, coupled with `ACTION_MAIN`, identifies a replacement home screen.

> what's the alternative to it

Not having it. Either you have this category, or you do not.

Comment: So can we not have a hard-wiring of some sort so that the first activity is already configured (by default) to some well known location. The idea is to remove that line and get such alternative. Ideas?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "So can we not have a hard-wiring of some sort so that the first activity is already configured (by default) to some well known location" -- I have no idea what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Please check the update in above question. The code in question will do the work of calling home screen. Then why do we need that line `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>` in manifest ? Removing it did nothing.

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "Removing it did nothing" -- quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html): "For an intent to pass the category test, every category in the Intent object must match a category in the filter. The filter can list additional categories, but it cannot omit any that are in the intent." Hence, if you have `HOME` in the `Intent`, `HOME` must be in the `<intent-filter>`. You are welcome to publish the complete source code to a reproducible test case if you have evidence to the contrary.

Comment: "if you have HOME in the Intent, HOME must be in the <intent-filter>" - I have the HOME in the <intent-filter> as mentioned in the doc. But I don't know if I have the HOME in the Intent. what's the line of code to add to achieve this ?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "But I don't know if I have the HOME in the Intent. what's the line of code to add to achieve this ?" -- `homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);`, as you typed into your question.

Comment: Please check the update in question. So in my manifest, I have a `UserActivity` in which I have a category home. The same I did in UserActivity.java adding the matching intent with `Intent homeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`. On pressing the home button, why I still not see my application as an option?

Comment: @SaurabhJain: "why I still not see my application as an option?" -- I have no idea. You are welcome to examine and experiment with the `Home` sample app in your SDK.

Comment: Possibly because you have set another launcher app as the default app in your phone? However I'm not fully sure about this.

Answer (score 5):

The category HOME is used to declare your application as a Home launcher. By putting this in the manifest then user will have the option to have your application open upon pressing the home button.

This is typically used when creating an application that will be used in a kiosk mode.

I do not believe there is an alternative to make an application a home launcher.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME)

Comment: So can we not have a hard-wiring of some sort so that the first activity is already configured (by default) to some well known location. The idea is to remove that line and get such alternative. Ideas?